# how to stream audio with tcpserversink using gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, audio-streaming, tcpserver

I need live-stream audio over Internet. Quick search in internet and I decide using Gstreamer. I has streamed successfully using udpsink, but it only work on LAN. I test with tcpserversink but it not working:

Server (IP: 113.160.166.87)

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="G:/Project/Gstreamer/TestContent/Em-Gai-Mua-Huong-Tram.mp3" ! decodebin ! mulawenc ! tcpserversink port=7001 host=0.0.0.0
```

Client:

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=113.160.166.87 port=7001 ! "audio/x-mulaw, channels=1, depth=16, width=16, rate=44100" ! mulawdec ! autoaudiosink
```

Someone help me! Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you encoding in the sender again ? can you try the following pipeline,

Sender:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location="G:/Project/Gstreamer/TestContent/Em-Gai-Mua-Huong-Tram.mp3" ! audioparse ! tcpserversink port=7001 host=0.0.0.0
```

Receiver:

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=7001 host=113.160.166.87 ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answers. Follow your command, receiver had receive packets and play audio. But it is not live stream, the sender stream in 30 second, the audio file is 5m30s. Do I need using some payload like rtpL16pay?