# How to live stream audio with tcpserversink using gstreamer

Tags: audio, gstreamer, live-streaming

I need live-stream audio over Internet. Quick search in internet and I decide using Gstreamer. I has streamed successfully using udpsink, but it only work on LAN. Asking in stackoverflow: [how to stream audio with tcpserversink using gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520255/how-to-stream-audio-with-tcpserversink-using-gstreamer) but it just stream over tcp, not live stream.

Sender:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location="G:/Project/Gstreamer/TestContent/Em-Gai-Mua-Huong-Tram.mp3" ! audioparse ! tcpserversink port=7001 host=0.0.0.0
```

Receiver:

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=7001 host=113.160.166.87 ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink
```

Do I need make file source tranform to live source before tcpserversink? And How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your sender pipeline, basically replace audioparse to mpegaudioparse because you are sending mp3 file .

Sender:

> gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc
>   location="G:/Project/Gstreamer/TestContent/Em-Gai-Mua-Huong-Tram.mp3"
>   ! mpegaudioparse ! tcpserversink port=7001 host=0.0.0.0

Receiver:

> gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=7001 host=113.160.166.87 ! decodebin
>   ! autoaudiosink

Or

> gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=7001 host=113.160.166.87 !
>   mpegaudioparse ! mad ! autoaudiosink

Comment: What command to play audio at recevier? I used "gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=7001 host=113.160.166.87 ! mpg123audiodec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink -v" and "gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=7001 host=113.160.166.87 ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink" but don't work

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=7001 host=113.160.166.87 ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink should work! make sure your volume is not muted and also do check if you have multiple outputs. use the following pipeline first and see if you can hear audio on the client side: gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! autoaudiosink

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I can hear audio when using command: gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! autoaudiosink . When I use  gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=7001 host=113.160.166.87 ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink , it just show Pipeline is PREROLLING...

Comment: can you try the receiver pipeline as following: gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=7001 host=113.160.166.87 ! mpegaudioparse ! mad ! autoaudiosink . Also can you confirm that in your query the above pipeline works (sender: gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location="G:/Project/Gstreamer/TestContent/Em-Gai-Mua-Huong-Tram.mp3" ! audioparse ! tcpserversink port=7001 host=0.0.0.0 reciever: gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=7001 host=113.160.166.87 ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink) ? Make sure you have  mpegaudioparse and mad plugins installed on both sender and receiver  machines (gst-inspect-1.0 should tell)

Comment: Mad plugins isn't installed in gstream version 1.0. Google it and it seem only in version 0,1. I don't know how to add mad plugin to version 1.0.